# HTMLed and JQuery Mobile popups (with dynamic content)

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery 1.10 and JQM 1.4 for a mobile web app. For the user language system I use the lightweight framework [nirus/HTMLed](http://nirus.github.io/HTMLed/) framework which is initialized on document ready.

However, I load html files dynamically inside jQuery popups (when they trigger). Obviously, HTMLed is already executed and won't replace (translate) the labels embeded in newly added html.

Example label in any static html or dynamically added html:

```
<h1>label.page</h1>
```

Example JSON for replacing with English text:

```
{"label.page" : "Hello World"}
```

**Are there other (javascript) ways to replace dynamically added labels without a refresh?**

Other than that, nice framework and thanks!

*I've let the author know about this post.*

EDIT:

Below some extra code to understand what I intend to do.

***First the HTML popup itself (multi purpose):***

```
<!-- Popup -->
<div data-role="popup" id="popup-wrapper" class="ui-content">
    <div id="popup-container"></div>
</div>
```

***I use the Hammer library for multi-gestures:***

```
Hammer('#someDiv').on("tap", function(event) {
    $('#popupContainer').load('someHTMLfile.html'); // Child div of the popup to load dynamic content
    $('#popupWrapper').popup("open", { transition: "pop" }); // the jQuery Popup opens
});
```

***With jQuery Mobile events I get rid of all the loaded html content from the #popupContainer:***

```
$('#popupWrapper').bind({
    popupafterclose: function(event, ui) {
        $(popupContainer).children().detach(); // clean up the #popupContainer to default
    }
});
```

BTW, your example code did work with the jQuery event (third block code), but did not with the Hammer event (second block code). Hope this clarifies the issue.

EDIT:

Forgot to add an example html content...

```
<div class="title">United States</div>
<div class="subtitle">Introduction</div>
<div class="mainContent">The United States of America (USA), commonly referred to as the United States (U.S.), America, or simply the States</div>

<div class="title">China</div>
<div class="subtitle">Population</div>
<div class="mainContent">1,351 billion (2012)</div>

<!-- etc. -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/P5xf7/10/

NOTE: You will have to add an ID to your `<h1>` tag.  If you could supply us with more code then we could probably give you a jQuery selector to get the `<h1>` without having to add an ID to it.  You will also need to remove the dot "." between `label.page`.

Code from the fiddle is below...

```
<h1 id="myHeader">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>

<script>    
    function loadHtmlIntoJqueryPopup(jsonString)
    {
        alert('About the change the header text...');
        //jsonString holds your: {"labelpage" : "Hello World"}
        //do whatever you do to load the html content into the window
        //turn the json into a js object
        var myObj = jQuery.parseJSON( jsonString );
        jQuery("#myHeader").text(myObj.labelpage);
    }
    loadHtmlIntoJqueryPopup('{"labelpage":"Hello World"}');
</script>
```

Comment: And this fiddle is slightly different.  Hard to tell exactly what you're asking for.  But in this version it checks the contents of H1 before replacing it.  http://jsfiddle.net/P5xf7/14/

Comment: Thanks, this works! Just to elaborate: Now, right after the empty popup receives the .load() hmtl content, your function above is called and replaces all the labels in the popup before it opens. Unfortunately, it does get a little harder to handle multiple languages. Could it be an idea to parse an entire en-GB.properties file after the dynamic html content is loaded in the popup. With conditional statements I can parse other JSON files (e.g. es-ES.properties). I will try to figure this out ^^ Thanks again! (See extra code below to understand my problem)

Answer (score 0):

Added new functionality based on your suggestion. Check the latest example proj on GitHub

http://nirus.github.io/HTMLed/